# Solution of the differential equation $\ddot{x}(t)=\alpha\dot{x}(t)x(t)+\beta x(t)^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve the following nonlinear differential equation:
$$\ddot{x}(t)=\alpha\dot{x}(t)x(t)+\beta x(t)^3$$
with initial conditions:
$x(0)=x_0$ and $\dot{x}(0)=x_1$
Is it possible to solve it without the use of numerical techniques?
Thanks.

Comment: If this is homework, please say so. It would help you to show your working so far too.

Comment: It isn't. It's a differential equation whose solutions can show chaotic behaviour and I have to solve it in order to generate a signal similar to noise. I would like to know if there is a periodical solution solving it analytically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't involve $t$ directly, so you can turn it into a first-order equation by letting $y=\dot{x}$ and then $$\ddot{x}=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=y\frac{dy}{dx}$$.
Then let $z=y/x^2$ and the equation becomes separable.
I get $$z^{\beta}e^{\alpha z}=Ax$$ for any $A$.  That can be solved using the Lambert W function, so $t=\int dx/[x^2W(...)]$